# Why the output of the program is like this?

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
int i=2;printf("%d,%d,%d\n",i++,i++,i);
return 0;
}
```

Output of the program is incorrect in my opinion ! Please help me out.

Comment: Order of evaluation of function parameters is undefined.

Comment: Moreover, the post-increment hasn't to be done immediately but can be delayed to the next sequence point. That's way such expressions does not work, even the order of evaluation is defined.